# Visualstudio SQLite select Datetime

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have to do a cross platform app in Visual Studio for a school project. Now I'm having trouble with the SQLite database. I save individual drink data as follows.

```
public class Drink
   {
       [PrimaryKey,AutoIncrement]
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public double Volume { get; set; }
       public DateTime Drinktime { get; set; }
       public double Size { get; set; }
   }
```

Among other things with a timestamp (Drinktime). So far so good, now my problem is that I want to read the drinks from the database after this time stamp.

My goal is now to write a function how I can call up all drinks between a certain point in time (DateTime Format) and now .

```
public List<Drink> GetAllDrinks()
       {
           lock (locker)
           {
               if (database.Table<Drink>().Count() == 0)
               {
                   return null;
               }
               else
               {
                   return database.Table<Drink>().ToList();
               }
           }
       }
```

but unfortunately I don't know how I can do it and after many hours of research without success I hope that one of you can help me. I only managed to read all the drinks.

Can someone help me there?

greetins Marv00

Answer (score 2):

use LINQ

```
var all = return database.Table<Drink>().ToList();

return all.Where(a => a.DrinkTime >= myDateTime).ToList();
```

Comment: If that helps you, be sure to define it as a valid answer.